# Proguard NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, google-play-services, proguard, fragmentpageradapter, android-proguard

Today I've updated my gradle to use the latest play services:

**build.gradle**

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'
```

**app.gradle**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
```

I use proguard to obfuscate code and I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: my.package.adapters.MyPagerAdapter
```

I tried adding this to proguard file:

```
-keep class my.package.adapters.MyPagerAdapter { *; }
```

but with no luck. With the previous version of play services no problem.
I get this error with every class that extends **FragmentPagerAdapter** from package android.support.**v13**.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.

Any help? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent FragmentPageAdapter derived class to be obfuscated, you need the following rule for proguard:

```
-keep class * extends android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter { *; }
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using right proguard configuration? Have you set to true 'minify' property? Is your proguard configuration section like proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'C:/blblabla/proguard-rules-1.5.2.pro'

Answer (score 0):

If you are multidexing your application, please consider using multiDexKeepFile property or multiDexKeepProguard property in your project level build.gradle.

More information here https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Basically you need to specify which classes to keep in your main dex file for the app to start correctly without crashing. I personally ended up using multiDexKeepProguard after making sure proguard wasn't the problem.